# Xcode 6: Sprite node does not come in contact with other sprite node when tapped? Falls off screen?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm working in Swift and have created an `SKSpriteNode` to be the ground in my game. I've set it to the proper position and made the physics body as wide as the screen:

```
//Ground
        var groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "groundBar")
        var groundBar = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
        groundBar.setScale(2)
        groundBar.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2)
        groundBar.hidden = true

        self.addChild(groundBar)

        var ground = SKNode()

        ground.position = CGPointMake(0, groundTexture.size().height)
        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height*2))

        ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false



        self.addChild(ground)
```

Then I have another `SKSpriteNode` that is the character in my game, and when tapped I have this character jump up and to the right:

```
//Savior character
        var saviorTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "character")
        saviorTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

        savior = SKSpriteNode(texture: saviorTexture)
        savior.setScale(1)
        savior.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.4)

        savior.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: savior.size.height/2)
        savior.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        savior.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        self.addChild(savior)




 override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            savior.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0) //pt it returns to?
            savior.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(5, 30)) //direction/height that it jumps }
```

Before it is tapped, the character sits on the ground node and therefore doesn't fall off the screen. When tapped, however, the character jumps up and falls off the screen. It's as if it doesn't come in contact with the ground.

I've tried resizing the ground, repositioning the ground, but the character still falls off the screen. Mind you that when the vector is (0,30) and it just jumps straight up, it doesn't fall off the screen.

What is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried making it so you can see the physics bodies? In your view controller you can do `skView.showsPhysics = true` and see if the physics bodies are where you think they are. Also, be sure that their physicsBody.collisionBitMask are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller you can do `skView.showsPhysics = true` and see if the physics bodies are where you think they are. Also, be sure that their `physicsBody.collisionBitMask` are not the same.